# Как написать свой API?

Tags: мобильные-приложения

Такой вопрос, если надо разработать приложение для телефона, или сайт, то нужно реализовывать общение сервер-пользователь. Для этого, если я правильно все понимаю, используется API. Такой вопрос, долго ли самому писать API, что нужно знать для этого? Где научиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратимся к Википедии:

> API (интерфейс программирования приложений, интерфейс прикладного
>   программирования) (англ. application programming interface, API
>   [эй-пи-ай][1]) — набор готовых классов, процедур, функций, структур и
>   констант, предоставляемых приложением (библиотекой, сервисом) или
>   операционной системой для использования во внешних программных
>   продуктах.

Итак, мы узнали, что API это лишь некий набор различных элементов программного кода, с помощью которого внешние приложения могут с нами общаться.

Для начала вам нужно сесть и обрисовать в деталях, что будет пересылаться от вашего приложения к пользователю, когда это будет пересылаться, кем. И наоборот, то есть от пользователя к приложению.

Например, вы сделали некую таблицу результатов, скажем, бегунов. Где каждый бегун бежит дистанцию, в конце у него есть определенный результат - время, за которое он её пробежал. И он хочет воспользоваться своей программой-клиентом, чтобы отправить свои данные на сервер результатов. Его программа клиент может иметь например такое API:

POST: /result {"name":,"time":,"distance":}
GET: /result, где параметрами могут выступать те же name, time (например, самые быстрые бегуны на данной дистанции) и distance
т.е, например: /results?name=Vasya&distance=10
и вам вернется лучший Васин результат на дистанции 10 километров. 
GET: /results, вернет вам список всех бегунов (в реальной жизни он может быть очень большим, поэтому здесь используют ограничения - limit и offset)

Вам нужно где-то хранить все эти данные, чаще всего, настроить базу данных, наладить контакт с ней. Фактически, реализовать внутреннее API между приложением и базой данных.

API - это такой язык общения между двумя приложениями. Все зависит от вашей задачи, простейшее API можно и за полчаса написать, а можно делать несколько месяцев.